# How to set Gurobi to stop after the objective value reaches a certain threshold in Julia?

Tags: julia, linear-programming, cplex, gurobi, integer-programming

I am trying to run a minimization problem for an MIP using Gurobi in Julia. I would like it to stop after it has found a solution that is below a certain threshold that I have set. I have found ways online to do this in other programming languages, but nothing helpful for Julia. For various reasons, I cannot just use an MIP Gap setting either.

Is there a way to do this in Julia?

I tried finding solutions to this in other programming languages that Julia offers guides for, but they did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you budget on solution time rather than the quality, so typically in your code you would have:

```
set_optimizer_attribute(mo, "TimeLimit", 60) # Gurobi terminates after one minute
```

As far as I know, Gurobi does not have a parameter for "good enough" goal function value. You could however consider changing the goal function into a constraint such as:

```
@variable(m, x >= 0)
@variable(m, y >= 0)
@variable(m, b >=0 )


@constraint(m, 3*x + 2*y <= 500 + b)
@objective(m, Min, b)
```

In this example I assume we minimize `3*x + 2*y` and we consider the value of `500` to be "good enough".

Comment: What does the third argument in the objective do?

Comment: `m` is the JuMP `Model`, `Min` means minimization and `b` is the goal function. You minimize the value of `b`. `b` represents how far the actual function `3*x + 2*y` differs from 500. `500` is a sample "good enough" value - "a solution that is below a certain threshold that I have set"

Comment: *Normally you budget on solution time rather than the quality* No. Using a gap criterion is very common.